# Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am facing the error

```
Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor
```

with a pretty trivial code and can't figure where the error comes from. Running the same code in a Jupyter notebook works.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# inherit from this base class
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class SimpleDense(Layer):

    def __init__(self, units=32):
        '''Initializes the instance attributes'''
        super(SimpleDense, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        '''Create the state of the layer (weights)'''
        # initialize the weights
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(name="kernel",
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                 dtype='float32'),
            trainable=True)

        # initialize the biases
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
        self.b = tf.Variable(name="bias",
            initial_value=b_init(shape=(self.units,), dtype='float32'),
            trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        '''Defines the computation from inputs to outputs'''
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b

# declare an instance of the class
my_dense = SimpleDense(units=1)

# define an input and feed into the layer
x = tf.ones((2, 1))
y = my_dense(x)

# parameters of the base Layer class like `variables` can be used
print(my_dense.variables)

# define the dataset
xs = np.array([-1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], dtype=float)
ys = np.array([-3.0, -1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0], dtype=float)


# use the Sequential API to build a model with our custom layer
my_layer = SimpleDense(units=1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([my_layer])

# configure and train the model
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=500,verbose=0)

# perform inference
print(model.predict([10.0]))

# see the updated state of the variables
print(my_layer.variables)
```

***Update: Error-Message including backtrace***

```
In user code:

    File "keras\engine\training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "keras\engine\training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "keras\engine\training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "keras\engine\training.py", line 808, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "Dense_Layer.py", line 19, in build
        initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).
    
    Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
  File "Dense_Layer.py", line 19, in build
    initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "Temp\__autograph_generated_filexvnq5chx.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
  File "Dense_Layer.py", line 19, in build
    initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "Dense_Layer.py", line 54, in <module>
    model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=500,verbose=0)
```

Python Version:
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

CopyRight: Deeplearning.ai

Comment: Post the entire error message including back track…

Comment: The error is due to the fact that the shape of `xs` is `(6,)` and therefore the model's `input_shape` is `None`, so `input_shape[-1]` doesn't work. If you add `xs = xs.reshape(-1, 1)` then the shape of `xs` becomes`(6,1)` and the model's `input_shape` becomes `(None, 1)` and therefore `input_shape[-1]` returns `1` and the code works as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That's definitly a mistake I should have found.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an 'Input layer' to the Sequential API will fix the issue.

Could be an issue with different tensorflow versions. That could be the reason it worked in Jupyter notebook

Changes:

```
# use the Sequential API to build a model with our custom layer
    input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,)) # Added Newly
    my_layer = SimpleDense(units=1)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([input_layer, my_layer]) # Added input_layer here.
```

Full Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# inherit from this base class
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class SimpleDense(Layer):

    def __init__(self, units=32):
        '''Initializes the instance attributes'''
        super(SimpleDense, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        '''Create the state of the layer (weights)'''
        # initialize the weights
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(name="kernel",
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                                 dtype='float32'),
            trainable=True)

        # initialize the biases
        b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
        self.b = tf.Variable(name="bias",
            initial_value=b_init(shape=(self.units,), dtype='float32'),
            trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        '''Defines the computation from inputs to outputs'''
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b

# declare an instance of the class
my_dense = SimpleDense(units=1)

# define an input and feed into the layer
x = tf.ones((2, 1))
y = my_dense(x)

# parameters of the base Layer class like `variables` can be used
print(my_dense.variables)

# define the dataset
xs = np.array([-1.0,  0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], dtype=float)
ys = np.array([-3.0, -1.0, 1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 7.0], dtype=float)


# use the Sequential API to build a model with our custom layer
input_layer = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,)) # Added Newly
my_layer = SimpleDense(units=1)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([input_layer, my_layer]) # Added input_layer here.

# configure and train the model
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=500,verbose=0)

# perform inference
print(model.predict([10.0]))

# see the updated state of the variables
print(my_layer.variables)
```